# SELECT image from preview before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a javascript function to let people select a primary image after selected their images and right before the upload.
I'm using an image-uploader JS lbirary from Christian Bayer. It gives several options, for example I can preview the images, I can delete them etc. Bt it also means that I only have this in my html part:

```
<div class="input-images" name="thumbnailimage"></div>
```

So I can't really use onclick event or anything here. I'm trying to select the images by adding each preview image an onclick event and I want to put it's path into a hidden input, so I can upload it to a different table.
This is how my div looks like after adding images:

```
<div class="uploaded">
<div class="uploaded-image" data-index="0" id="image-0">
<img src="blob:http://localhost/11388451-d0be-454c-aabe-20a77e8c8835">
<button class="delete-image"><i class="iui-close"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="uploaded-image" data-index="1" id="image-1">
<img src="blob:http://localhost/5920bf98-8b23-4bb2-b573-20fe94620437">
<button class="delete-image"><i class="iui-close"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the images this way:

```
$('#image-upload').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length) {
  var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('uploaded-image');
  console.log(foo);
  } else {
    foo = "";
    }
});
```

But how can I add onclick event to each image to select them and be able to copy it to a hidden input?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think I can add Christian Bayer's JS file to it, because I had to download it and can't insert it like a bootstrap or jquery link.

Comment: It's unclear the relationship of things. I would look for the library via a hosted CDN or at least include a link to the location so Docs can be reviewed. What specifically is not working? What did you expect to have happen? Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: The problem isn't with his code. I'm trying to add my own Javascript code, so users can click on the images in preview to select the primary image. And I'd like to add the selected image to a hidden input, so I can upload it to a different table. Sorry if my explanation is a bit poor, I'm trying my best.

Comment: You're using https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that one.

Comment: I setup the follow test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mbvqoyn4/2/ So now it makes more sense. There is already a Delete button. When you click on an image preview, what do you want to have happen? where do you want to store the Path?

Comment: I'd like to add it to a hidden input, so users can't see it, but I can upload it's path to a different table, than the other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mbvqoyn4/14/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var selected = [];
  $('.input-images-1').imageUploader();

  $(".uploaded").on("dblclick", "img", function() {
    console.log("Double Click on Image", $(this).attr("src"));
    selected.push({
      id: $(this).parent().data("index"),
      src: $(this).attr("src")
    });
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected-image");
    console.log(selected);
  });
});
```

I moved the event to a Double Click as there is already a Click event assigned to the parent of the Image that is bubbling up:

```
function(e) {
  d(e)
}
```

But you can see how you can bind an event to the dynamically created object using the `.on()` method. I then store these in an array and you can then send this data to a hidden field or use AJAX to send it to your server in the background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have 2 questions. For some reason if I resize my chrome and trying it in mobile view, it doesn't write anything to the console. And my second question, how can I get the image's original path from blob? Because if I send this blob: src to my database, it won't find the right path.

Comment: Mobile devices are hard to use Double Click. But that should not be an issue when testing in Chrome with smaller view. The SRC is the local path to the preview. I'm assuming you want to POST the image data so that it gets uploaded and the path on the server is what you want; and that's going to be handled by the server side scripting, not in JS.

Comment: You mean it's not even possible to get it's path correctly with JS?

Comment: @randomdude you can after it's been uploaded. Unless you know the server side path and the name that will be used ahead of time.

Comment: I wanted to do it before the upload because I don't know what to do if they close the site after image upload, without finishing the whole form. The images will be stored in the database for no reason. Could you tell me how to avoid it? Ofc I accept your answer because u solved my problem, but I'd appreciate if you could tell me this last question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @randomdude that will depend on your Server Side script. If you know you're uploading all images to one path, `../upload/`, and you use a specific naming pattern, then you can know it will be something like `../upload/01202021_user_1.jpg`. Otherwise you will not know until it's uploaded where it will be on the server and the name. JS only has access to local details.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think I need to rethink this again.

Comment: @randomdude consider uploading to a temp location (not publicly available) in this step. If there are further steps, where the user can confirm this is the image they want to use, then at that time the file can be moved and path can be saved to the DB. Then you can easily clear out the temp location every so often.